# How can I select all HTML items by name ending with a "name"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I select all HTML items by name ending with a `name` using jQuery

```html
<input type="text" name="[0].LastName" value="Smith">
<input type="text" name="[1].LastName" value="James">
<input type="text" name="[2].LastName" value="Wilson">
<input type="text" name="[3].LastName" value="Peterson">
```

For instance if I wanted in jQuery loop through the multiple elements but only select Element Names ending with `].LastName`, therefore it should only return the 3 elements above.

Comment: Does this help? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors `/* <a> elements with an href ending ".org" */
a[href$=".org"] {
  font-style: italic;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comment in the code below. But also, you could just name all of those elements the same `name` and then when the form submits, the data will be combined into a comma delimited string.

```js
// Just pass a valid CSS Selector to JQuery:
let elements = $("input[name$='LastName']");

console.log(elements);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="[0].LastName" value="Smith">
<input type="text" name="[1].LastName" value="James">
<input type="text" name="[2].LastName" value="Wilson">
<input type="text" name="[3].LastName" value="Peterson">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[attr$=value]` to select elements whose `attr` attribute ends with `value`.

```js
$('input[name$="Name"]').each((i, el) => console.log(el));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="[0].LastName" value="Smith">
<input type="text" name="[1].LastName" value="James">
<input type="text" name="[2].LastName" value="Wilson">
<input type="text" name="[3].LastName" value="Peterson">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ends with` selector:
https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/
e.g:

```
$("[name$='.LastName']")
```